# Merge new GET param with current route in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a question. I'm creating a view file for product listing which have filter function. For example, My current Url is

```
mysite/category/electronics?p=1
```

And in my template I have **a** tag to add a some filter criteria. When click on a, I want my uri will be `mysite/category/electronics?p=1&c=2` for example.

But I don't know what's the best practice to generate href for **a** tag, by current uri(app.request.uri) or generate uri from route (use path())..... Waiting for help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are on the route name `product_show` I'd say you should use `path()`

`path("product_show", { p : 1, c : 2, i : "another_parameter"})`

PS: If you have a large amount of parameters your should use `url_encode` to make it more readable.

Ref: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/url_encode.html#url-encode

And finally and good to know. `app.request.query.all` will give you all current query parameters in your current url.